# Is the US saving enough money from the USMCA to pay for the Wall?

Tags: united-states, politics, mexico, trade

President Trump just tweeted [this](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1073195450033950720?s=21):

> I often stated, “One way or the other, Mexico is going to pay for the Wall.” This has never changed. Our new deal with Mexico (and Canada), the USMCA, is so much better than the old, very costly & anti-USA NAFTA deal, that just by the money we save, MEXICO IS PAYING FOR THE WALL!

My question is, is President Trump right that the United States saves enough money from his renegotiation of NAFTA into the USMCA to pay for his proposed border wall?

In the past he has asked Congress for $25 billion for the Wall.

Comment: Once again we have to say that for this to be considered 'notable' we have to show that people are taking this claim seriously.

Comment: @DJClayworth Breitbart's reporting on the subject doesn't make any claim that it's true, only reporting on the fact that Trump tweeted this. https://www.breitbart.com/politics/2018/12/13/donald-trump-mexico-paying-for-border-wall-with-usmca-trade-deal/

Comment: @DJClayworth We have had that question up before, and the result was: since it is the person that has the office of president of the United States, then it is automatically notable, simply because if he makes the statement, it will have an impact and people will start referring to it. And when that happens, people will want to check up on that claim. And that is when they land **here**.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm going on.  Brietbart isn't supporting the tweet as true, just reporting that he did tweet it.

Comment: One of the big problems is that, even among the people who think that USMCA will pay for the wall, they can't even agree HOW it will pay for the wall.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelK . For anyone not familiar with NAFTA and USMCA, the claim seems plenty reasonable. And if they don't buy in to the popular depiction that trump lies a lot, there's no reason to doubt it. In other words, the fact trump said it will leave many believing it, so let's do what the site is for and check that out.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the existing meta question: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/should-off-the-cuff-claims-by-donald-trump-be-considered-notable-without-evidenc

Comment: @DJClayworth Oh, **you** wrote answer on the Meta question that says we have to take what Trump says as a notable claim! :-D

Comment: Maybe I'd forgotten that.

Comment: Does "the money we save" mean extra money for US businesses and workers or extra money for the US gubmint through increased tax revenues and tariffs? Who knows, ask Trump. Without knowing this, the question is not clear.